# Access control in swift 4

Tags: swift, access-control, swift4

While upgrading to `Swift4` from `Swift3`, I got some issues related to `access control`.

Here is the sample code. Which was there in `Swift3`, working fine in past times -

```
open class MyClass {
    private let value: Int
    static var defaultValue: Int { return 10 }
    public init(value: Int = MyClass.defaultValue) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

To make the code run in `Swift4`, I have to change `access control` for `defaultValue` to `public`.
Here is the `Swift4`, compiling version

```
open class MyClass {
    private let value: Int
    static public var defaultValue: Int { return 10 }
    public init(value: Int = MyClass.defaultValue) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

While I was wondering what is going on, I tried to remove `open` access control for `MyClass`, it allowed me to remove `access` identifier for `defaultValue`. Even can put it to `private`.

```
class MyClass {
    private let value: Int
    private static var defaultValue: Int { return 10 }
    public init(value: Int = MyClass.defaultValue) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

I understand all the access identifiers, but I am not able to understand this behaviour. Especially the first case where `xcode` forced me to change `access control` of `defaultValue` to `public`.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My original answer (shown below) is now mostly outdated – the beginnings of the resilience model [are to be implemented in Swift 4.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0193-cross-module-inlining-and-specialization.md) with the introduction of the `@inlinable` and `@usableFromInline` attributes, corresponding to the old `@_inlineable` and `@_versioned` attributes.

In addition, and more importantly, the rule for what default arguments of publically accessible functions can reference has changed again. To recap the previous rules:

- In Swift 3 there was no enforcement of what access level such default argument expressions could reference (allowing your first example where `defaultValue` is `internal`).
- In Swift 4, such a default argument could only refer to declarations exposed as a part of the module's interface, *including* those that aren't otherwise directly visible to users in another module (i.e `@_versioned internal`).

However in Swift 4.2, with the implementation of [SE-0193](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0193-cross-module-inlining-and-specialization.md), [the rule is now](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/15666) that the default argument expression of a publicly accessible function can *only* refer to publicly accessible declarations (not even `@inlinable internal` or `@usableFromInline internal`).

I *believe* this is paving the way for the displaying of default argument expressions in a module's generated interface file. Currently Swift just shows an unhelpful `= default`, but I believe this will change to actually show the default argument. This can only realistically happen with this new access-control restriction in place (**Edit**: This is [now happening](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/18579)).

---

#### Old answer (Swift 4)

This change is due to the work towards a resilience model that is already available via underscored attributes (`@_inlineable`, `@_versioned`, `@_fixed_layout`), but is yet to be officially finalised (so you probably shouldn't be using these attributes yourself yet). You can read about the [full proposed details of the resilience model here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/LibraryEvolution.rst), as well as the the [Swift evolution discussion on it here](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171002/040061.html).

In short, an *inlineable* function is one whose *implementation*, as well as declaration, is exposed as a part of a module's interface and can therefore be inlined when called from another module. An inlineable function must therefore also be publically accessible to begin with (i.e `public` or higher).

What you're running into is a change that makes [default argument expressions for publically accessible functions inlineable](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/LibraryEvolution.rst#default-argument-expressions), meaning that they must be available to be evaluated directly in the calling module's binary. This reduces the overhead of calling a function with default parameter values from another module, as the compiler no longer needs to do a function call for each default argument; it already knows the implementation.

I don't believe this change is officially documented in the release of Swift 4 itself, but it is confirmed by Swift compiler engineer Slava Pestov, [who says](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/10348#issue-236628385):

> Swift 3.1 added resilience diagnostics for inlineable code, which is not an officially supported feature, but in Swift 4 we switched these checks on for default argument expressions as well.

So if you have a publically accessible function with a default argument expression (such as `MyClass.defaultValue` in your case), that expression can now only refer to things that are also a part of that module's interface. So you need to make `defaultValue` publically accessible.

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to make a `private` function's declaration part of a module's interface (which would allow for your usage of it in a default argument expression). The attribute that would facilitate this is `@_versioned`, but it is forbidden with `(file)private` due to the following reasons [given by Slava Pestov](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20171002/040093.html):

> It would be a trivial change to allow `@_versioned` on `private` and
>   `fileprivate` declarations, but there are two pitfalls to keep in mind:
>
> - Private symbols are mangled with a ‘discriminator’ which is basically a hash of the file name. So now it would be part of the ABI,
>     which seems fragile — you can’t move the private function to another
>     source file, or rename the source file.
> - Similarly, right now a `@_versioned` function becoming public is an ABI compatible change. This would no longer work if you could have
>     `private @_versioned` functions, because the symbol name would change if
>     it became `public`.
>
> For these reasons we decided against “`private versioned`” as a concept.
>   I feel like `internal` is enough here.

You *could* achieve this with a `@_versioned var defaultValue` though:

```
open class MyClass {

    private let value: Int

    @_versioned static var defaultValue: Int {
        return 10
    }

    public init(value: Int = MyClass.defaultValue) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

The declaration of `MyClass.defaultValue` is now exported as a part of the module's interface, but still cannot be directly called from another module's code (as it's `internal`). However, the *compiler* of that module can now call it when evaluating the default argument expression. But, as said earlier, you probably shouldn't be using an underscored attribute here; you should wait until the resilience model has been finalised.

Comment: Fascinating, captain!